# authorize paypal payment on client and capture payment on server

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, paypal, payment

I want to authorize the payment with Paypal on the client-side (React) and then the payment is to be captured on the server-side (ASP.NET). Is this possible using any library provided by Paypal? How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/rest-webhooks/) from Paypal API. You can configure a webhook listener and subscribe it to any [event](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/event-names/) you are interested in getting notified of. Paypal will then notify you (by sending an HTTP POST notification to a URL listening on your server that you have to provide when you configure the webhook) when any of the events you subscribed to occur.